# Overwrite the Contents of a File in C

Tags: c, file

I am writing a code that forks multiple processes. They all share a file called "character." what I want to do is to have every process read the 'only character' in the file and then erase it by putting its own character so the other process can do the same. The file is the only way the processes can communicate each other. How can I erase the 'only character' in the file and put a new one in its place. I was advise to use freopen() (which closes the file and reopens it erasing its previous contents) but I am not sure if it is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: What's the performance of your implementation using freopen? What performance do you want?

Comment: take a look at file locking in Google

Comment: That sounds like a good recipe for trouble. Why not use the mechanims meant fot inter process communication?

Comment: Well because overwriting the existing character is only done less than one hundred times I think there will not be much difference using a better efficient way. However, because I want my code be readable and somewhat professional I would like a better way than freopen().

Comment: Because is a project and I am not allowed to use inter process communication, but only a file to achieve the communication.

Comment: Well you are basically making a shared mailbox technically.... so it is a pseudo IPC.

Comment: Read everything about files from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ Yes it is a C++ oriented site, but that part is about the C library.

Comment: Open the file in update mode (`+` in the `fopen()` mode).  Read the character; rewind the file; write the new character; flush the output; rewind; reread; rewind; rewrite; rinse and repeat.  There's no guarantee about the sequence in which processes will read that, and a number of processes may read the same character and a number of the characters generated by different processes may get overwritten before being read, so there are synchronization issues.  But the mechanics get the letter overwritten and only require standard C and do not require `freopen()`.  I didn't claim it was efficient.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If I'm reading the question correctly, even that won't guarantee the results - there's still going to be race conditions.  Offhand, I don't see any platform-independent way to solve this.  Depending on the implementation, maybe `fopen()`/`fseek()`/`fread()`/`fwrite()` could do it as long as all buffering is disabled.

Comment: Whether `freopen()` does what you claim it will do depends on the file mode you specify.  More importantly, however, it is probably counterproductive.  If all the processes involved share handles on the *same* open file description (by inheritance across the `fork()`) then you have better-defined semantics than if they have unrelated streams that merely happen to be associated with the same file (as would arise from `freopen()`).

Comment: @AndrewHenle, if use of `fork()` justifies assuming POSIX semantics then there are [rules to be followed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01).  If they *are* followed, then "regardless of the sequence of handles used, implementations shall ensure that an application, even one consisting of several processes, shall yield correct results: no data shall be lost or duplicated when writing, and all data shall be written in order, except as requested by seeks." Even then, however, POSIX does not guarantee that all input is seen exactly once.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I posted an answer with code that does what I think the OP is asking.  No telling how hard it'll thrash his filesystem though.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to reopen the file.  That gains you nothing.  If you're worried about each process buffering input or output, disable buffering if you want to use `FILE *`-based stdio functions.

But if I'm reading your question correctly (you want each process to replace the one character in the file when it's a specific value is held in the file, and that value changes for each process), this will do what you want, using POSIX `open()` `pread()`, and `pwrite()` (you're already using POSIX `fork()`, so using low-level POSIX IO makes things a lot simpler - note that `pread()` and `pwrite()` eliminate the need for seeking.)

I'll say this is what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
// header files and complete error checking is omitted for clarity
int fd = open( filename, O_RDWR );

// fork() here?

// loop until we read the char we want from the file
for ( ;; )
{
    char data;
    ssize_t result = pread( fd, &data, sizeof( data ), 0 );

    // pread failed
    if ( result != sizeof( data ) )
    {
        break;
    }

    // if data read matches this process's value, replace the value
    // (replace 'a' with 'b', 'c', 'z' or '*' - whatever value you
    //  want the current process to wait for)
    if ( data == 'a' )
    {
        data = 'b';
        result = pwrite( fd, &data, sizeof( data ), 0 );
        break;
    }
}

close( fd );
```

For any decent number of processes, that's going to put a lot of stress on your filesystem.

If you really want to start with `fopen()` and use that family of calls, this *might* work depending on your implementation:

```
FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "rb+" );

// disable buffering
setbuf( fd, NULL );

// fork() here???

// loop until the desired char value is read from the file
for ( ;; )
{
    char data;

    // with fread(), we need to fseek()
    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET );
    int result = fread( &data, 1, 1, fp );
    if ( result != 1 )
    {
        break;
    }

    if ( data == 'a' )
    {
        data = 'b';
        fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET );
        fwrite( &data, 1, 1, fp );
        break;
    }
}

fclose( fp );
```

Again, that assumes I'm reading your question properly.  Note that the POSIX rules John Bollinger mentioned in his comments regarding multiple handles don't apply - because the streams are explicitly not buffered.

Comment: Yes, I think `pread()` and `pwrite()` are excellent choices here.  The trick with a stream-based approach is the requirement, when it applies, for a process to seek to a known position when making its handle on the file the "active" one.  Without any other synchronization, if there is a need to seek then you need to seek+read/write *atomically*.  `pread()` and `pwrite()` not only do that, but because they do not change the file offset, they also avoid obligating other threads / processes to seek in the first place.